# What exactly is the difference between conjure animals and woodland beings?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, summoning

In D&D  5e, the Ranger can get Conjure Animals as a 3th level spell, and Conjure Woodland Beings as a 4th level spell.

I'm unsure what they do differently, their descriptions seem to be largely identical; but if they really are identical, why are they both available for the Ranger?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The differences are in the spells' descriptions.

> ## Conjure Animals
>
> You summon *fey spirits* that take the form of **beasts** and appear in unoccupied spaces that you can see within range. Choose one of the following options for what appears:
>
> - One **beast** of challenge rating 2 or lower
> - Two **beasts** of challenge rating 1 ar lower
> - Four **beasts** of challenge rating 1/2 or lower
> - Eight **beasts** of ehallenge rating 1/4 ar lower

> ## Conjure Woodland Beings
>
> You summon *fey creatures* that appear in unoccupied spaces that you can see within range. Choose one of the following options for what appears:
>
> - One **fey** creature of challenge rating 2 or lower
> - Two **fey** creatures of challenge rating 1 or lower
> - Four **fey** creatures of challenge rating 1/2 or lower
> - Eight **fey** creatures of challenge rating 1/4 or lower

*Conjure Animals* lets you summon beasts (well, spirits that take the form of beasts); *Conjure Woodland Beings* lets you summon the actual fey creatures.

Comment: I always imagined there was a clear distinction when they had to refer to the summoned creatures vaguely as "beings" and animals were not included. Do you think this may be relevant?